# MYSQL Set column value with AVG value from group by result

Tags: mysql, group-by

Currently I am trying to fill up empty column values. I want to use an average of a column where the rows are similar.

With the following query I get the rows I need to update:

```
SELECT `Voertuigsoort`, `Merk`, `Handelsbenaming`, `Datum eerste toelating`, `Inrichting`, `Massa rijklaar`, `Cilinderinhoud`, `Brandstof omschrijving`
FROM selectie_1
    WHERE  `Brandstofverbruik gecombineerd` = '' AND `Brandstof omschrijving` != 'elektriciteit'
GROUP BY `Voertuigsoort`, `Merk`, `Handelsbenaming`, `Datum eerste toelating`, `Inrichting`, `Massa rijklaar`, `Cilinderinhoud`, `Brandstof omschrijving`;
```

With the following query I get the average values, using the same GROUP BY:

```
SELECT  AVG(`Brandstofverbruik gecombineerd`) avg_bal
            FROM    selectie_1 
            WHERE   `Brandstofverbruik gecombineerd` != '' AND `Brandstof omschrijving` != 'elektriciteit'
            GROUP   BY `Voertuigsoort`, `Merk`, `Handelsbenaming`, `Datum eerste toelating`, `Inrichting`, `Massa rijklaar`, `Cilinderinhoud`, `Brandstof omschrijving`;
```

Both queries run fine, but my attempt at updating the results from the first query with the average values from the second query, does not; I get 'cannot specify target table'.

This is my attempt:

```
UPDATE
    selectie_1
SET
    `Brandstofverbruik uitgerekend` = (
        SELECT  AVG(`Brandstofverbruik gecombineerd`) avg_bal
            FROM    selectie_1
            WHERE   `Brandstofverbruik gecombineerd` != '' AND `Brandstof omschrijving` != 'elektriciteit'
            GROUP   BY `Voertuigsoort`, `Merk`, `Handelsbenaming`, `Datum eerste toelating`, `Inrichting`, `Massa rijklaar`, `Cilinderinhoud`, `Brandstof omschrijving`)
WHERE `Brandstofverbruik gecombineerd` = '' AND `Brandstof omschrijving` != 'elektriciteit';
```

Is my idea at least correct? And how should I combine both queries properly?

Comment: what is the matching id in both queries. because first query is group one but can have multiple rows for same group.

Comment: @JitendraYadav that should be selectie_1.id

Comment: do you need `group by` in first query which returns number of records to be updated.?

Comment: not necessarily, but only the rows of the first query should be updated, note the WHERE difference in query 1:  `Brandstofverbruik gecombineerd` = ''  and query 2: `Brandstofverbruik gecombineerd` = !''

Comment: bcz first thing, if there are multiple ids with same fields which are used in group by , you will get only first record in group by , so that'w why we should exclude group by for first query.

Comment: and i think join would not be based on `id`. I think it would be based on `group by` fields.

Comment: thanks @JitendraYadav, I thought the same regarding join fields. It is indeed possible there are multiple id's per group by. Do you know how i should rewrite my query?

Comment: yes will give you a solution in 5 mins, verify that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before doing updates make sure you're doing it right. You can verify that using a select query which we'll be converting to `UPDATE` query.

```
SELECT s1.id, avg_bal
FROM selectie_1 s1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT AVG(`Brandstofverbruik gecombineerd`) avg_bal, `Voertuigsoort`, `Merk`, `Handelsbenaming`, `Datum eerste toelating`, `Inrichting`, `Massa rijklaar`, `Cilinderinhoud`, `Brandstof omschrijving`
    FROM selectie_1 s2
    WHERE `Brandstofverbruik gecombineerd` != '' AND `Brandstof omschrijving` != 'elektriciteit' 
    GROUP BY `Voertuigsoort`, `Merk`, `Handelsbenaming`, `Datum eerste toelating`, `Inrichting`, `Massa rijklaar`, `Cilinderinhoud`, `Brandstof omschrijving`
) as tmp ON s1.`Voertuigsoort` = tmp.`Voertuigsoort`
        AND s1.`Merk`  = tmp.`Merk`
        AND s1.`Handelsbenaming`  = tmp.`Handelsbenaming`
        AND s1.`Datum eerste toelating`  = tmp.`Datum eerste toelating`
        AND s1.`Inrichting`  = tmp.`Inrichting`
        AND s1.`Massa rijklaar`  = tmp.`Massa rijklaar`
        AND s1.`Cilinderinhoud`  = tmp.`Cilinderinhoud`
        AND s1.`Brandstof omschrijving`  = tmp.`Brandstof omschrijving`
WHERE s1.`Brandstofverbruik gecombineerd` = '' AND s1.`Brandstof omschrijving` != 'elektriciteit';
```

Corresponding `UPDATE` query would be like this.

```
UPDATE selectie_1 s1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT AVG(`Brandstofverbruik gecombineerd`) avg_bal, `Voertuigsoort`, `Merk`, `Handelsbenaming`, `Datum eerste toelating`, `Inrichting`, `Massa rijklaar`, `Cilinderinhoud`, `Brandstof omschrijving`
    FROM selectie_1 s2
    WHERE `Brandstofverbruik gecombineerd` != '' AND `Brandstof omschrijving` != 'elektriciteit' 
    GROUP BY `Voertuigsoort`, `Merk`, `Handelsbenaming`, `Datum eerste toelating`, `Inrichting`, `Massa rijklaar`, `Cilinderinhoud`, `Brandstof omschrijving`
) as tmp ON s1.`Voertuigsoort` = tmp.`Voertuigsoort`
        AND s1.`Merk`  = tmp.`Merk`
        AND s1.`Handelsbenaming`  = tmp.`Handelsbenaming`
        AND s1.`Datum eerste toelating`  = tmp.`Datum eerste toelating`
        AND s1.`Inrichting`  = tmp.`Inrichting`
        AND s1.`Massa rijklaar`  = tmp.`Massa rijklaar`
        AND s1.`Cilinderinhoud`  = tmp.`Cilinderinhoud`
        AND s1.`Brandstof omschrijving`  = tmp.`Brandstof omschrijving`
SET s1.`Brandstofverbruik uitgerekend` = tmp.avg_bal
WHERE s1.`Brandstofverbruik gecombineerd` = '' AND s1.`Brandstof omschrijving` != 'elektriciteit';
```

Comment: @Maarten Hartman, please verify this resultset, it will contain `id` that which record will be updated and `avg_bal` the value which will be updated.

Comment: thanks, I get 'Column 'Brandstof omschrijving' in where clause is ambiguous'

Comment: use table alias in all columns. I'll update the answer

Comment: see the updated answer, In outer where clause `s1` is added for both columns. Try now. first try select query, if that is correct then run update.

Comment: thanks a lot, the query is currently running, after that I have to verify the results, there are many rows so it might take a while. I will let you know :)

Comment: thanks a lot, the results are correct. This helped me a lot :)